# Real life usage of languages analysis?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, lexical-analysis

I could easily use parts of compiler (e.g scanning, parsing, syntax analysis) to write my own compiler, or code analyzer (like generating class diagrams and other)... but there are some other uses of those algorithms and tools (except from natural languages) in real life?

I'm supposed to make a project for my studies using those algorithms and we are allowed to do anything that use those tools and I would like to do something more useful than another diagrams generating app.

Comment: You can use LALR parsers to implement multi-level protocols.

Comment: woah, I didn't known that, thanks! any other examples?

Comment: Yes, and what about something that applies to non-programmers as well? Like something data-related or something similar?

Comment: @user3924850: I think SO people are about to close your question as "off topic" due to something about "opinionated answers".  I suggest the closers check the answers, to see if they are opinions, or facts, before they close.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit (see my bio) uses generalized compiler technology to support automating massive code base changes:  code migration, modernization, re-architecting, optimization. It has been used in a variety of serious, real world tasks.  (It does code analysis to decide where to apply change).  DMS is not your grandma's parser generator; see my essay on "Life After Parsing."